# Make a <pre> tag look correctly indented with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a `<pre>` & `<code>` tag which looks like:

```
<pre><code>somevar = array.join("-")
      somevar.split("-")
      puts "#{somevar} is cool yay!"
      if somevar.nil?
          puts 'it's nil!'
      end
      </code></pre>
```

How can I make it look like it's correctly indented? It actually looks like:
[image: code]

and it should look like:

[image: good code]

I tried jQuery's 'trim()' function and 'replace()' with this RegEx:

- `/^\s*/`
- `/\s*$/`
- `/^\s+|\s+$/gi`

But no way. How should I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ensure the code in the HTML has no preceding whitespace on the newlines - `pre` won't collapse multiple whitespace.

Comment: um yeah just seen it. I guess instead of trim() you can apply some regex on line. I just gotta find a regex that fits

Comment: @zad0xsis If it's only ever one tab that's in the way, you can use `replace(/^\t/', '')`. If you can guarantee it's only one *tab*, you could use `substring(1)`.

Answer (score -1):

The `<pre>` tag will interpret its contents literally -- so you need to add some spaces.

```
<pre><code>somevar = array.join("-")
      somevar.split("-")
      puts "#{somevar} is cool yay!"
      if somevar.nil?
          puts 'it's nil!'
      end
      </code></pre>
```

should become

```
<pre><code>      somevar = array.join("-")
      somevar.split("-")
      puts "#{somevar} is cool yay!"
      if somevar.nil?
          puts 'it's nil!'
      end
      </code></pre>
```